# Adding the values ​from DataGridView to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, winforms

Nothing happens when I click the add button. I want to add the values ​​from DGV's cells to SQL table.

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  USING SQL
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CANER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='Student Automation DB';Integrated Security=True");

    for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.Rows.Count; i++){

        if (mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null){
            continue;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO students VALUES('" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[0].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[1].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[2].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[3].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[4].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i - 1].Cells[5].Value +"')";

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that if the value in the `mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0]` HAS A VALUE, then that row will not be written to the DB? … `if (mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null) { continue; }`… ? So, if the first cell HAS a value AND is not `null`, then DO NOT write that row to the DB?... Are you sure you don’t want `if (mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0] == null) { continue; }`

Comment: If you value your database, use parameterized queries. You are wide open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in the posted code, IF `Cells[0]` IS `null`, THEN add that row to the DB. I will assume this is backwards and will use IF `Cells[0]` IS NOT `null`, THEN add that row to the DB.

Also, it seems unnecessary to “open” and “close” the DB connection with each iteration of the loop. I replaced this construct with `using` statements instead to ensure the connection gets closed properly.

In addition, I am pretty sure that `mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0]` will NEVER be `null.` Therefore, the code will NEVER add any rows to the DB. `mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` may be `null` but the code never checks this.

Lastly, you should be aware, that your code is open to SQL injection. This is frowned upon in almost all environments and the code would be rejected because of this. In most cases, it is wise to “parameterize” your queries. It is a little more work/code; however, it is well worth the effort to prevent a malicious user from messing up your data base. There are many examples of this with a simple google search on parametrized query. If you have problems implementing a parameterized query, let me know and I can add an example.

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //  USING SQL
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CANER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='Student Automation DB';Integrated Security=True")) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      con.Open();
      for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
        if (mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null) {
          cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO students VALUES('" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','" + mainTable.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value +"')";
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right about "null". I solved the problem by taking the values ​​with TextBox. Thus, there was less workload. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the column-names to the query? Like "INSERT INTO students (column_name1, column_name2...) VALUES ('x','y'...)"?

Comment: why do you substract i-1? since your started your loop by 0, there should be no issue with the row-count. Have you set up a breakpoint in the loop to see if it's is actually working? Maybe set a breakpoint at con.Close() as well and check the "cmd"-values.

Comment: Because keep the loop until you get to null. Then read the values ​​before null. So the values ​​entered by the user.